# The Steipler's Gaon idea behind voting in Eretz Yisrael

Tags: sources-mekorot, zionism, voting, steipler

In sefer B'ein Chazon by Rabbi Shmuel David Munk, there is a letter in response to what the Steipler Gaon is supposed to have said on voting in the Israeli elections. The Steipler Gaon held that showing the world how many frum-Yidden there are, would be a great thing, and thus, voting would also be a good thing to do.

> הנה נתפרסם בעתונים מכתב שנדפס בשם מע"כ הדר"ג בעניין הבחירות, שלפי דעת מע"כ הדר"ג ראוי להשתתף בהם כדי להראות את רבוי מספרם של שומרי התורה, ואשר הנמנע מלהשתתף גורם לחילול השם ח"ו. והנה ידוע, שבעיקר הענין, אם להשתתף בבחירות אם לאו, נחלקו הדעות. וטעם המקילין הוא מפני שיש צורך בדבר להצלת הדת. אכן מע"כ הדר"ג הזכיר בדבריו טעם אחר, ומשמע מזה, שטעם ההצלה אינו נראה בעיניו עיקר כ"כ. [(B'ein Chazon, p. 17)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49024&st=&pgnum=17&hilite=)

Does anyone know where this letter from the Steipler Gaon could be found? Is it in Kiryana D'Igarta? If so, where? I have [this](https://www.eichlers.com/karyana-deigrata-3-volumes-hs29434.html) volume of Kiryana D'Igarta, is it included in here?

Comment: Sorry maybe I am just not seeing it - but where does it say that it comes from the Steipler?

Comment: I heard in a shiur that this whole sefer is mostly based on correspondence between the author and the Steipler and the letters of the Steipler.

Comment: Are you looking for an exact copy of the above - or places where he tells people to participate in the elections?

Comment: Well, I have the three copies I linked from Kiryana D'Igarta, so I like to have the exact copy of what it says above so I can look it up in the physical copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Steipler spends a good part of the first section on the third volume discussing voting.

Refer to the third volume [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/162779/p/16/t/0.46243899611147521234/fs/WSKXnBsMXQDwa2diGye6UNHWE2jCWXaltXCsghgOrrpS/start/0/end/7/c) which addresses the notion of voting in Knesset elections in general.

There he mentions that by voting for the chareidi parties it is a big mitzvah, and it is an obligation, as it is both public and beneficial to the existence of the religion - all of which are echoed in the extract you bring:

> בעיקר הדבר כך דעתי העניי' נוטה שמצוה רבה להצביע לרשימה החרדית ושיש בזה ממש הצלת הדת לפי המצב כעת כי בעניני שמירת התורה לא שייך בטחון בלא השתדלות והחובה לעשות כל הנראה באופן טבעי טוב ומועיל לקיום הדת
>
> Mainly this is the way it is, in my opinion, the matter tends to be very commanding to vote for the Chareidi (ultra-Orthodox) list and that there is actually a saving of the religion according to the current situation because in matters of keeping the Torah there is no security without effort and the duty to do what is apparently good and beneficial to the existence of the religion.

Comment: Fantastic and sharp as always, Dov! Keep shteiging! Would it also be possible to translate the piece for me on p. 4 (beginning with: גם לענ"ד אפי' מי שחושב שזהו אתחלתא דגאולה)? Thanks!

Comment: Ok v quick and rough translation (sorry) "Even in my humble opinion, even those who think that this is the beginning of redemption, even though it really is not, because it is a change, it is more bitter to discover that the nations in recent generations have not interfered in matters of preserving the religion, which is not the case. Nevertheless, whoever thinks that the change from the rule of foreigners to the rule of the free and wicked from the seed of Israel is the beginning of its redemption is nothing but wrong,

Comment: ...but not evil, peace be upon him, that it is permissible to speak slanderously and contemptuously about him in public, even what is not the case that the rabbi went to accompany him, a wicked man, let his name be erased, it is clear that he walked as if on coals But he saw it as a kind of royal peace and as a way of going after some carcass of a poritz or a minister in previous times because of ways of peace, and if he did not find the courage to omit it, it was not allowed to speak slander about him.

Comment: ...And in general, I wonder why they have the honour to mention the names of specific people who will not be saved from the prohibition of defamation and gossip that is even true."

Comment: Thank you, tizku l'mitzvos Dov! Keep up the great work!